# Creating Ludo app in HTML || Cannot switch chance between user

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am facing an issue with the js code given in the dropbox source link below (https://www.dropbox.com/s/dc6jb2aka8ffqr9/game.js). When the user has just one crown out in the open and its almost at the finish line, if the user gets a higher number than required then ideally the chance should switch between the users but that is not happening.

HTML code is given below.

```css
body{
    margin:0px;
    font-family: Serif;
    color:rgba(255,255,255,255);
    font-weight:bold;
    
     -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
    background-color: black;
background-size: 56.57px 56.57px;
}


.mainframe{
    display: flex;
    height:100vh;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

}
.welcome{
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    z-index:+99;
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.welcome .setting{
    width:300px;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top:20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.7),inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    border:0.5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.setting .name{
    padding-bottom: 12px;
}
.setting .footer{
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #00e34c;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family:serif;
    padding: 6px 0px;
    color:rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}
.welcome .setting .name input{
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding:5px;
    outline:none;
    width:80%;
    margin:10px 0px;
}

.play{
    outline: none;
    border:0.5px solid black;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding:5px 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    cursor:pointer;
}
.play:hover{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.ri{
    background-color:rgba(247, 22, 45,0.6);
    border:0.5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(247, 22, 45,0.9),inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(247, 22, 45,0.7);
}

.gi{
    background-color:rgba(0, 227, 76,0.6);
    border:0.5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0, 227, 76,0.9),inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 227, 76,0.7);
}

.yi{
    background-color:rgba(247, 187, 5,0.6);
    border:0.5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(247, 187, 5,0.9),inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(247, 187, 5,0.7);
}

.bi{
    background-color:rgba(4, 195, 201, 0.6);
    border:0.5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(4, 195, 201,0.9),inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(4, 195, 201,0.7);
}
input::placeholder{
    color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
.note{
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 5px 4px;
}
.welcome .setting .logo img{
    width:20%;
}

.ludoboard{
    background-color: white;
    border:0.5px solid black;
    width:600px;
    height:600px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(15,40px);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(15,40px);
}

.playername{
    font-size:20px;
}

.diceboard{
    margin:5px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height:600px;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.mdiceboard{
    display: none;
}
.diceboard .info{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
.centerbox{
    grid-column: 7/10;
    grid-row: 7/10;
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    border-top:60px solid #00e34c;
    border-bottom:60px solid #04c3c9 ;
    border-left:60px solid #f7162d;
    border-right:60px solid #f7bb05 ;
}
.red{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
background-color: #f7162d;
border:0.5px solid #9e0616;
    grid-column: 1/7;
    grid-row: 1/7;
}
.redsafe{
background-color: #f7162d;
border:0.5px solid #9e0616;
}
.playerzone{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 50px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.crown{
    grid-column: 1/3;
    
}
.player{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color: white;
    opacity:0.9;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
.green{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  background-color:#00e34c ;
border:0.5px solid #039634;
    grid-column: 10/16;
    grid-row: 1/7;
}
.greensafe{
  background-color:#00e34c ;
border:0.5px solid #039634;  
}
.step{
    border:0.5px solid #b3b3b3;
}
.blue{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
     background-color:#04c3c9 ;
border:0.5px solid #027478;
    grid-column: 1/7;
    grid-row: 10/16;
}
.bluesafe{
    background-color:#04c3c9 ;
border:0.5px solid #027478;
}
.yellow{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
     background-color:#f7bb05;
border:0.5px solid #9c7605;  
    grid-column: 10/16;
    grid-row: 10/16;
}
.yellowsafe{
     background-color:#f7bb05 ;
border:0.5px solid #9c7605;  
}
.astep{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.rp{
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.astep span:nth-child(1){
    top:0px;
}
.astep span:nth-child(2){
    top:4px;
}
.astep span:nth-child(3){
    top:8px;
}
.astep span:nth-child(4){
    top:12px;
}
.astep span:nth-child(5){
    top:16px;
}
.astep span:nth-child(6){
    top:20px;
}
.astep span:only-child{
    top:auto;
}
/*
.astep::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width:0px;
}
*/

.rp{
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius:50%;
}

.rp:hover{
    border-radius: 50%;
    border:0.5px solid red;
}

.r{
    color:#f7162d;
}
.g{
    color:#00e34c;
}
.b{
    color:#04c3c9;
}
.y{
    color:#f7bb05;
}

.material-icons{
    opacity:0.9;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.rstop{
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #f7162d 25%, #ffbdc4 25%, #ffbdc4 50%, #f7162d 50%, #f7162d 75%, #ffbdc4 75%, #ffbdc4 100%);
background-size: 15px 10px;
}
.gstop{
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #00e34c 25%, #b0ffcc 25%, #b0ffcc 50%, #00e34c 50%, #00e34c 75%, #b0ffcc 75%, #b0ffcc 100%);
background-size: 15px 10px;  
}
.ystop{
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #f7bb05 25%, #fff2c7 25%, #fff2c7 50%, #f7bb05 50%, #f7bb05 75%, #fff2c7 75%, #fff2c7 100%);
background-size: 15px 10px;
}
.bstop{
background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #04c3c9 25%, #bdfdff 25%, #bdfdff 50%, #04c3c9 50%, #04c3c9 75%, #bdfdff 75%, #bdfdff 100%);
background-size: 15px 10px;    
}

.winner-r{
    width:100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url(crown.png);
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .fixed{
    position: fixed;
}
    .mainframe{
    flex-direction: column;
}
    .diceboard{
        display: none;
    }
    
    
    .mdiceboard{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
        width: 100vw;
    justify-content: space-between;
        margin:10px 0px;
}
.mdiceboard .info{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
/*
    .r-dice,.g-dice,b-dice,{
        display: none;
    }
*/
.ludoboard{
    background-color: white;
    border:0.5px solid black;
    width:100vw;
    height:100vw;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(15,1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(15,1fr);
}
    .centerbox{
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    grid-column: 7/10;
    grid-row: 7/10;
/*   background-color: aqua;*/
        background-image: url(center.jpg);
        background-size: cover;
    border:0px solid red;
}
    .playerzone{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 16px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.crown{
    grid-column: 1/3;
    width:90%;
    align-self: center;
    align-items: center;
    
}
.player{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color: white;
    opacity:0.9;
    width:1fr;
    height:1fr;
}
}

.r-dice{
    background-color:#f7162d;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border-radius:5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border:0.5px solid black;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 8px black;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    color:white;
    font-size:30px;
    text-shadow:0px 0px 1px black;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.g-dice{
    background-color:#00e34c;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border-radius:5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border:0.5px solid black;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 8px black;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    color:white;
    font-size:30px;
    text-shadow:0px 0px 1px black;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.b-dice{
    background-color:#04c3c9;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border-radius:5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border:0.5px solid black;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 8px black;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    color:white;
    font-size:30px;
    text-shadow:0px 0px 1px black;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.y-dice{
    background-color:#f7bb05;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border-radius:5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border:0.5px solid black;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 8px black;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    color:white;
    font-size:30px;
    text-shadow:0px 0px 1px black;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/dc6jb2aka8ffqr9/game.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ludo Board Game v1.0</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="icon" href="icon.png" type="image/png"/>
    <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.0.0/animate.min.css"
  />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<audio id="diceSound">
  <source src="dice.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
<audio id="killedSound">
  <source src="killed.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
<audio id="winSound">
  <source src="win.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
<audio id="inoutSound">
  <source src="inout.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
<audio id="stepSound">
  <source src="step.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
<div class="fixed">
  <!-- <div class="welcome">
       <div class="setting">
                <div class="logo">
                    <img src="icon.png" class="logo">
                </div>
                <div class="name">
                    <input type="text" class="ri" placeholder="Red player name...">
                    <input type="text" class="gi" placeholder="Green player name...">
                    <input type="text" class="yi" placeholder="Yellow player name...">
                    <input type="text" class="bi" placeholder="Blue player name..."><br>
                    <button class="play">Play</button><br>
                    <span class="note">if only two players playing enter only two names</span>
                </div>
                <div class="footer">
                    Made by Akky Srivastava Akash with ❤ 
                </div>
       </div>
   </div> -->
    <div class="mainframe">
       <div class="diceboard">
           <div class="info">
               <span class="playername">
                  Player 1 
               </span>
               <div class="r-dice" onclick="dice(this,0)">   
                0
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="info">
               
               <div class="b-dice" onclick="dice(this,3)">
                   0
               </div>
               <span class="playername">
                  Player 4 
               </span>
           </div>
       </div>
       
       <div class="mdiceboard">
           <div class="info">
               <span class="mplayername">
                  Player 1 
               </span>
               <div class="r-dice" onclick="dice(this,0)">
                   0
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="info">
                <span class="mplayername">
                  Player 2 
               </span>
               <div class="g-dice" onclick="dice(this,1)">
                   0
               </div>
              
           </div>
       </div>
        <div class="ludoboard">
            <div class="red">
                <div class="playerzone">
                <div class="player"><span onclick="movered(this,0)" class="rp r material-icons">stars</span></div>
                <div class="player"><span onclick="movered(this,1)" class="rp r material-icons">stars</span></div>
                <div class="player"><span onclick="movered(this,2)" class="rp r material-icons">stars</span></div>
                <div class="player"><span onclick="movered(this,3)" class="rp r material-icons">stars</span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="astep step"></div>
            <div class="astep step"></div>
            <div class="astep step"></div>
            <div class="green">
                <div class="playerzone">
                <div class="player"><span onclick="movegreen(this,0)" class="rp g material-icons">stars</span></div>
                <div class="player"><span onclick="movegreen(this,1)" class="rp g material-icons">stars</span></div>
                <div class="player"><span onclick="movegreen(this,2)" class="rp g material-icons">stars</span></div>
                <div class="player"><span onclick="movegreen(this,3)" class="rp g material-icons">stars</span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="astep step"></div>
            <div class="astep greensafe"></div>
            <div class="astep gstop"></div>
            <div class="astep step rstop"></div>
            <div class="astep greensafe"></div>
            <div class="astep step"></div>
            <div class="astep step"></div>
            <div class="astep greensafe"></div>
            <div class="astep step"></div>
            <div class="astep step"></div>
            <div class="astep greensafe"></div>
            <div class="astep step"></div>
            <div class="astep step"></div>
            <div class="astep greensafe"></div>
            <div class="astep step"></div>
            
            <div class="astep step"></div>
            <div class="astep rstop"></div>
            <div class="astep step"></div>
            <div class="astep step"></div>
            <div class="astep step"></div>
            <div class="astep step"></div>
            
            <div class="centerbox"></div>
            
            <div class="astep step"></div>
            <div class="astep step"></div>
            <div class="astep step"></div>
            <div class="astep step gstop"></div>
            <div class="astep step"></div>
            <div class="astep step"></div>
            
            <div class="astep step"></div>
            <div class="astep redsafe"></div>
            <div class="astep redsafe"></div>
            <div class="astep redsafe"></div>
            <div class="astep redsafe"></div>
            <div class="astep redsafe"></div>
            
            <div class="astep yellowsafe"></div>
            <div class="astep yellowsafe"></div>
            <div class="astep yellowsafe"></div>
            <div class="astep yellowsafe"></div>
            <div class="astep yellowsafe"></div>
            <div class="astep step"></div>
            
            <div class="astep step"></div>
            <div class="astep step"></div>
            <div class="astep step bstop"></div>
            <div class="astep step"></div>
            <div class="astep step"></div>
            <div class="astep step"></div>
            
            <div class="astep step"></div>
            <div class="astep step"></div>
            <div class="astep step"></div>
            <div class="astep step"></div>
            <div class="astep ystop"></div>
            <div class="astep step"></div>
            
            
            
            
            <div class="blue">
                <div class="playerzone">
                <div class="player"><span onclick="moveblue(this,0)" class="rp b b material-icons">stars</span></div>
                <div class="player"><span onclick="moveblue(this,1)" class="rp b b material-icons">stars</span></div>
                <div class="player"><span onclick="moveblue(this,2)" class="rp b b material-icons">stars</span></div>
                <div class="player"><span onclick="moveblue(this,3)" class="rp b b material-icons">stars</span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="astep step"></div>
            <div class="astep bluesafe"></div>
            <div class="astep step"></div>
            <div class="yellow">
                <div class="playerzone">
                <div class="player"><span onclick="moveyellow(this,0)" class="rp y material-icons">stars</span></div>
                <div class="player"><span onclick="moveyellow(this,1)" class="rp y material-icons">stars</span></div>
                <div class="player"><span onclick="moveyellow(this,2)" class="rp y material-icons">stars</span></div>
                <div class="player"><span onclick="moveyellow(this,3)" class="rp y material-icons">stars</span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="astep step"></div>
            <div class="astep bluesafe"></div>
            <div class="astep step"></div>
            <div class="astep step"></div>
            <div class="astep bluesafe"></div>
            <div class="astep step"></div>
            <div class="astep step"></div>
            <div class="astep bluesafe"></div>
            <div class="astep step ystop"></div>
            <div class="astep bstop"></div>
            <div class="astep bluesafe"></div>
            <div class="astep step"></div>
            <div class="astep step"></div>
            <div class="astep step"></div>
            <div class="astep step"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="diceboard">
           <div class="info">
               <span class="playername">
                  Player 2 
               </span>
               <div class="g-dice" onclick="dice(this,1)">
                   0
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="info">
               
               <div class="y-dice" onclick="dice(this,2)">
                   0
               </div>
               <span class="playername">
                  Player 3
               </span>
           </div>
       </div>
       
       <div class="mdiceboard">
           <div class="info">
               
               <div class="b-dice" onclick="dice(this,3)">
                   0
               </div>
               <span class="mplayername">
                  Player 4 
               </span>
           </div>
           <div class="info">
               
               <div class="y-dice" onclick="dice(this,2)">
                   0
               </div>
               <span class="mplayername">
                  Player 3
               </span>
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
<script src="game.js"></script>
</div>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: any error ur getting in console ?

Comment: No. Acutally its just the first line i.e. var rdice = document.getElementsByClassName('r-dice'); which is creating the issue and I am unable to understand why so.